# How do you display transparency when it's NOT selected?

Tags: transparency

I've got a semi-transparent texture that I want to display in the preview mode (so I can take screenshots for a client without having to fully render the scene). When I select the plane with the transparency, it displays correctly but if it is UNSELECTED it just shows up solidly (see image attached for settings and for the example of the issue). I've tried to use Alpha clip but it gives a hard edge and not a nice soft gradient that you get with the Alpha Blend.

Any help on this would be amazing, thanks!
[image: Selected and non selected image showing the texture as solid when unselected and semi transparent when selected]

[image: Snapshot of settings used for material and textures]

Comment: Hello :). The UI looks pre 2.8. Which engine do you use?

Comment: @JachymMichal Hello! :) Ah yes, I am using Blender 2.79 as that was what I was using when I begun this project.

Comment: Well, since 2.8, there is Eevee. A pretty accurate *realtime* render engine that would surely fit your intended use :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Ahh okay- maybe it would just be best to switch to the 2.8 version! Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Definitely, Eevee is a godsend :).